# Play different sounds on click menu

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I'm working on a project where I need to play a diferent audio file for every div on a menu.
I'm using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var playing = false;  
    $('.punt').click(function() {  
        if (playing == false) {  
            $(this).play();  
            playing = true;  
        } else {  
            $(this).pause();  
            $(this).currentTime=0;  
           playing = false;  
        }  
    });  
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="menu">  
<ul>  
<li><div class="punt primertf">Transecte 1<audio id="player"  src="so/itinerari.mp3"></audio></div></li>  
<li><div class="punt segontf">Transecte 2<audio id="player"  src="so/fontibonun.wav"></audio></div></li>  
<li><div class="punt tercertf">Transecte 3<audio id="player"  src="so/fontibondos.wav"></audio></div></li>  
<li><div class="punt quarttf">Transecte 4<audio id="player"  src="so/fontibontres.wav"></audio></div></li>  
<li><div class="punt cinquetf">Transecte 5<audio id="player"  src="so/fontibonquatre.wav"></audio></div></li>  
</ul>  
</div>
```

If instead of (this) I use a different class for each one it works, but I think it can be simple than this way. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is that you're confusing `$(this)` ([jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)) and `this` (DOM element). The jQuery object doesn't have play/pause methods or a `currentTime` property. Below is working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var playing = false,
        audioPlayers = $('.punt audio');
    $('.punt').click(function() {  
        if (playing == false) {  
            $(this).find('audio').get(0).play();  
            playing = true;  
        } else {  
            audioPlayers.each(function(){
                this.pause();
                this.currentTime=0;
            });  
           playing = false;  
        }  
    });  
});
```

`audioPlayers` is a cached jQuery object containing all the menu audio tags. When a menu item is clicked we do a check to see whether any audio is playing. If it isn't then we play the selected menu's audio by finding the child `audio` tag, getting the matched DOM element using [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) and then using `.play()`.

If audio is already playing we loop through every `audio` tag using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) then pause and reset the current time of each one. `this` can be used within the `.each()` loop as it references the `audio` tag directly.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kpk6y1dr/ (I've also removed the duplicate `id`s)

Comment: Thanks, but it's posible to stop the others sounds before play the new one in one click? I mean, now, if you click on the first element of the menu starts the first one, and if you click the second, the first sound stop but doesn't start the second after click another time.

Comment: @user3013881 - No problem, it's quite easy to do: http://jsfiddle.net/7avucak1/ - you just remove the `if...else` and the `playing` variable then move the code that plays the clicked audio underneath the `.each()` loop.

Comment: When I see it working I understand how and why it works, but I'm unable to create the code... The problem now is that there's no way to stop the sound until it finishes...

Comment: @user3013881 - I've made a small addition which fixes that issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7avucak1/1/